# centering content with max-width and side margins %

Tags: html, css

```
body {
  max-width: 1000px !important;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Trying to proportionally center my content, while keeping a max-width at 1000px seem to not work.. is there a work around this? It's important to keep the 5% margins for this project..

It aligns all my content to the left..

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestions.. I found that removing the max-width in the body, and adding it to the divs inside the body helped to keep the centered look, while using the 5% side margins..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to center the content of your page with a 5% margin left and right on resolution under 1000px you can use this code:

```css
.container{
  width:90%;
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  height:500px;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Over 1000px the content result centered in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following to your element to align items center.

```
div{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div> Loreum Ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can create a `div` and add `CSS` on that

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> Your html code placed here </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without touching the body tag. Div is just enough.

```css
.is-centered {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grey {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="is-centered grey">
    <p>this is centered!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for the suggestions.. I found that removing the max-width in the body, and adding it to the divs inside the body helped to keep the centered look, while using the 5% side margins..

```
body {
margin-right: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
height: 100%;}

<div style="max-width:1920px">content</div>
```